# uncaught typeerror:cannot set property 'action' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do a login, however receive "uncaught typeerror:cannot set property 'action' of undefined" error on the first line in readrecord() funtion and don't know how to solve it.

```
<script>
    function readrecord() {
    document.main.action = "Login.php";
    document.getElementById("op").value = "check";
    document.main.submit(); 
}

function Userdontexist() {
  alert("Username or Password is wrong");
}

function submitForm() {
    Traveler_Username = document.getElementById('Traveler_Username').value;
    Password = document.getElementById('Password').value;

        if (Traveler_Username == "" || Password == "") {
            alert("Need to fill al the fields");
            return;
      } else {
        readrecord();
}}
</script>

<?php
include 'DB_connection.php';
    if (isset($_REQUEST["op"])) $op = $_REQUEST["op"]; else  $op = "";
    if (isset($_REQUEST["Traveler_Username"])) $Traveler_Username = $_REQUEST["Traveler_Username"]; 
    if (isset($_REQUEST["Password"])) $Password = $_REQUEST["Password"];

if ($op=="check") {
    $query = "select * from users where Traveler_Username =".$Traveler_Username;
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0 ){
            alert("User do not exist");
            $Traveler_Username  = "";
            $Password   = "";
            header("Location: reg.php");
            exit;
        } else {
                $query = "select Password from users where Traveler_Username =".$Traveler_Username;
                $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
                $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
                $db_pass = $row["Password"];
                if ($Password == $db_pass){
                    $Traveler_Username = $row['Traveler_Username'] ;
                    $Password = $row['Password'] ;
                    } else {
                            echo '<script> Userdontexist(); </script>';
                    }
            } // end else
} // end if

?>
                <tr>
                <td style="width: 95px;">Username</td>
                <td dir="rtl" style=" text-align: center; width: 195px;">
                <form method="post" target="_blank">
                <input id="Traveler_Username" type="text" dir="rtl" size="10" />
                    </form>
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td class="he_shadow" style="text-align: center; width: 70px;">&nbsp;</td>
                <td style="width: 95px;">Password</td>
                <td dir="rtl" style=" text-align: center; width: 195px;">
                <form method="post" target="_blank">                
                    <input id="Password" name="Password" type="password" dir="rtl" size="10" />
                    </form>
                </td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td style="text-align: center; width: 70px;" rowspan="2">
                &nbsp;</td>
                <td style="width: 95px" rowspan="2">
                <form method="post" target="_blank">
                <input name="Submit1" type="submit" value="login"  onclick="readrecord()" style="width: 43px" />
                </form></td>
                <td style="text-align: center; border-bottom-color: #FF9900; width: 195px; height: 30px;">
                <input name="Reset1" type="reset" value="clear data" /></td>
                <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: center; border-bottom-color: #FF9900; width: 195px;">
                &nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td style="text-align: center; width: 70px;">
                &nbsp;</td>
                <td style="width: 95px">
                &nbsp;</td>
                <td style="text-align: center; border-bottom-color: #FF9900; width: 195px;">
                &nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>

</div>
```

What do I have to change in the code?

Comment: Clearly there is no `document.main`, why would there be, did you define it somewhere ?

Comment: Use jquery instead

Comment: `document.main` will look for an element like `<form name="main">`. There's no such element in your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was fixed, I had to change the name of the form as: `<form name = "main">`

Thank you Barmar.